# Model creating 1 model for each row

Tags: r, regression, forecasting

I have a timeseries and i want to create a regression model with it, the time series looks as follows :

```
  Date       Value PREDICTOR1 PREDICTOR2 PREDICTOR3 PREDICTOR4 PREDICTOR5 PREDICTOR6 PREDICTOR7 PREDICTOR8 PREDICTOR9 PREDICTOR10 PREDICTOR11 PREDICTOR12
  <date>     <dbl>         <dbl>              <dbl>      <dbl>             <dbl>             <dbl>     <dbl>        <dbl>                  <dbl>               <dbl>
1 2021-09-02  74             0.1                3.7        3.8               0.6               1.5      63.2          2.6                 -51900                 1.6
2 2021-09-03  74.4           0.1                3.7        3.8               0.6               1.5      63.2          2.6                 -51900                 1.6
3 2021-09-07  73.9           0.1                3.7        3.8               0.6               1.5      63.2          2.6                 -51900                 1.6
4 2021-09-08  73.7           0.1                3.7        3.8               0.6               1.5      63.2          2.6                 -51900                 1.6
5 2021-09-09  73.8           0.1                3.7        3.8               0.6               1.5      63.2          2.6                 -51900                 1.6
6 2021-09-10  73.7           0.1                3.7        3.8               0.6               1.5      63.2          2.6                 -51900                 1.6
```

From it I trained a model :

```
fit <-    df %>%
      model(
        tslm = TSLM(Value ~ PREDICTOR1+ PREDICTOR2+ PREDICTOR3+ PREDICTOR4+ PREDICTOR5 +PREDICTOR6+ PREDICTOR7+ PREDICTOR8 +PREDICTOR9 +PREDICTOR10 +PREDICTOR11 +PREDICTOR12)
    )
```

But I receive as result for report :

```
> report(fit)
# A tibble: 3,409 x 16
      id .model r_squared adj_r_squared sigma2 statistic p_value    df log_lik   AIC  AICc   BIC    CV deviance df.residual  rank
   <int> <chr>      <dbl>         <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl> <int>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>       <int> <int>
 1     1 tslm         NaN           NaN    NaN       NaN     NaN     1     Inf  -Inf  -Inf  -Inf   NaN        0           0     1
 2     2 tslm         NaN           NaN    NaN       NaN     NaN     1     Inf  -Inf  -Inf  -Inf   NaN        0           0     1
 3     3 tslm         NaN           NaN    NaN       NaN     NaN     1     Inf  -Inf  -Inf  -Inf   NaN        0           0     1
 4     4 tslm         NaN           NaN    NaN       NaN     NaN     1     Inf  -Inf  -Inf  -Inf   NaN        0           0     1
 5     5 tslm         NaN           NaN    NaN       NaN     NaN     1     Inf  -Inf  -Inf  -Inf   NaN        0           0     1
 6     6 tslm         NaN           NaN    NaN       NaN     NaN     1     Inf  -Inf  -Inf  -Inf   NaN        0           0     1
 7     7 tslm         NaN           NaN    NaN       NaN     NaN     1     Inf  -Inf  -Inf  -Inf   NaN        0           0     1
 8     8 tslm         NaN           NaN    NaN       NaN     NaN     1     Inf  -Inf  -Inf  -Inf   NaN        0           0     1
 9     9 tslm         NaN           NaN    NaN       NaN     NaN     1     Inf  -Inf  -Inf  -Inf   NaN        0           0     1
10    10 tslm         NaN           NaN    NaN       NaN     NaN     1     Inf  -Inf  -Inf  -Inf   NaN        0           0     1
```

So it created a model for each row of data in df (>3000), all of them non-usable.

Does somebody has a hint ?

P.S.
Is my first time

Comment: It does not make sense to apply a linear model on each row of a time series so that it only has one observation. You need more observations to get the coefficients and apply prediction. Sometimes when you group your data set and you have nested tibbles or data frames yes that might be doable. But here I don't think that's the case.

Comment: Yes I don't know why is applying 1 model for each row, is not my intention, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are right @AnoushiravanR, dataset is full of groups !!!

Comment: but after ungroup problem persists

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why this is not working.  It must be something in your data or R setup.
Here is an example of how this should work:

```
library(fable)

aq <- cbind(Date = as.Date(paste('2021', airquality$Month, airquality$Day, sep = '-')), airquality) |> 
  as_tsibble()
fit <- aq |> model(tslm = TSLM(Ozone ~ Solar.R + Wind + Temp))
report(fit)
Series: Ozone 
Model: TSLM 

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-40.485 -14.219  -3.551  10.097  95.619 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -64.34208   23.05472  -2.791  0.00623 ** 
Solar.R       0.05982    0.02319   2.580  0.01124 *  
Wind         -3.33359    0.65441  -5.094 1.52e-06 ***
Temp          1.65209    0.25353   6.516 2.42e-09 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 21.18 on 107 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared: 0.6059, Adjusted R-squared: 0.5948
F-statistic: 54.83 on 3 and 107 DF, p-value: < 2.22e-16
```

Comment: You are right, is something that is wrong, even with other models like ARIMA still giving 1 model per row